# Escaping literal s and ' while using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using sed in Gitbash for Windows to run through a body of XML texts marking up certain strings.

One of the strings concerned is:

```
S. Margaret's
```

which needs to be enclosed in an element like so:

```
<orgName id="16">S.Margaret's</orgName>
```

And so my script reads:

```
sed -e 's/S. Margaret's/<orgName id="16">S. Margaret's<\/orgName>/g'
```

Where I have escaped the forward slash in the  tag that I need to insert.

This throws an error "orgName: No such file or directory"

I suppose the issue is to do with the 's/ after Margaret, which is interpreted as the beginning of a new command, but how do I escape it? I've tried various combinations of backslashes but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complimenting [AlexP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47304299/5291015) to use escaped single quotes, I think you can also do double-quoting of the search/replace part, since you don't have any shell variables that needs expansion within it. This way you don't have to worry about the escaping the single quote or white space present. Also since the replacement text involves the `/` character, recommend changing `sed` default separator from `/` to `|` or any non-meta character of your choice.

```
sed -e "s|S. Margaret's|<orgName id=\"16\">S. Margaret's</orgName>|g" file
```

Answer (score 2):

`'` cannot be escaped inside a string in simple quotes. The shell sees your command as

```
sed -e 's/S. Margaret's/<orgName id="16">S. Margaret's<\/orgName>/g'
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        string in single quotes
                        ^ redirection operator
                         ^^^^^^^ file name to read input from
```

The usual construct is `'...'\''...'`.